# Error 497 in Play Store when trying to download specific apps?

Tags: google-play-store, downloading

I got my new Oneplus 3 today, but as I was trying to download certain apps (PvZ: Heroes, Whatsapp, and I'm assuming some more that I haven't tried yet), I would get the error "'App Name' can't be downloaded. Try again, and if the problem continues, get help troubleshooting. (Error code: 497)." For some apps (PvZ) the error pops up before it even starts loading the download. For others (Whatsapp), the download is mid-finished when it suddenly pops up and stops it from completing.

I tried downloading the same apps on my old phone (Samsung Galaxy Grand Prime), and even though I *already* had some of them installed, I couldn't update them. I tried on my friend's phone (Sony something), and it worked just fine.

I've tried looking online, but the only answers that I can find are "Uninstall updates for Play Store" or "Reset your phone to factory settings". I've done both of those things. My phone was in its factory settings literally half a day ago. What is happening, and how do I fix it ASAP? Also, why did it suddenly start happening on my old phone too? Any help is appreciated.